# Facebook Messenger: how to right-justify titles with RTL languages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

In Facebook Messenger platform, all titles are always justified to the left.  how do I show right-justified titles with RTL languages as Hebrew?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text formatting is not supported currently.